# How to change the priority function of Priority Queue in Python?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I want to implement Djikstra's algorithm in Python. Thus, when I store nodes of a graph in a priority Queue, I want them to be sorted in the order of their distances from the source node. How can I change the priority function so that the nodes are sorted in this way?
I am using the PriorityQueue Class in the queue module. By default, the integers entered are sorted in descending order, i.e., the priority of the smallest element is the highest. I want to enter a priority function which sorts nodes on the basis of the distance attribute in the node object. Following is the node class - 
class node
    node
    distance
Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation explains, `PriorityQueue`'s in python do not seem to accept custom comparison functions. However, you can use `min` and a regular list to achieve what you want since the `min` function call accepts a `key` function that decides what the smallest item is.

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, dist):
        self.dist = dist

def get_dist(node):
    return node.dist

nodes = [node(4), node(413), node(2), node(14), node(5)]

out = min(nodes, key=get_dist)
nodes.remove(out)
print('popped out:', out.dist) # popped out: 2

out = min(nodes, key=get_dist)
nodes.remove(out)
print('popped out:', out.dist) # popped out: 4

out = min(nodes, key=get_dist)
nodes.remove(out)
print('popped out:', out.dist) # popped out: 5
```